# Add source file to Eclipse Makefile C++ project

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I have created simple C++ Makefile Eclipse project in Ubuntu. Eclipse has created default Makefile:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

OBJS = cpp_makefile.o

ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE),debug)
    CFLAGS += -g
else ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE),run)
    CFLAGS += -O2
else ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE),linuxtools)
    CFLAGS += -g -pg -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
    LDFLAGS += -pg -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
else
    $(error Build mode $(BUILD_MODE) not supported by this Makefile)
endif

all:    cpp_makefile

cpp_makefile:   $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o:    $(PROJECT_ROOT)%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

%.o:    $(PROJECT_ROOT)%.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -fr cpp_makefile $(OBJS)
```

Everything goes fine in case I have only one source file. In case I create class `TestMe` with it's header and cpp file and add include header to main cpp file build fails. Looks like system can't find `TestMe.cpp`.

Error:

```
Building in: /home/a/cpp-workspace2/cpp_makefile/build/default
make -f ../../Makefile
g++ -c -O2   -o cpp_makefile.o /home/a/cpp-workspace2/cpp_makefile/cpp_makefile.cpp
g++  -o cpp_makefile cpp_makefile.o
/usr/bin/ld: cpp_makefile.o: in function `main':
cpp_makefile.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1c): undefined reference to `TestMe::TestMe()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../../Makefile:19: cpp_makefile] Error 1
Build complete (3 errors, 0 warnings): /home/a/cpp-workspace2/cpp_makefile/build/default
```

In case I use same source in Eclipse C++ Managed build project everything goes fine.  How to solve this problem in right way In Eclipse Makefile project?

cpp_makefile.cpp

```
#include "TestMe.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    TestMe testMe  = TestMe();
    return 0;
}
```

TestMe.h:

```
class TestMe {
public:
    TestMe();
    virtual ~TestMe(){};

};
```

TestMe.cpp:

```
#include "TestMe.h"
TestMe::TestMe() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will create a default `Makefile` for you, but it does not *manage* the `Makefile`(s) in a makefile-based project.  It cannot really do so while also allowing you to make your own makefile changes or supporting makefiles it did not generate itself.  If you want the build configuration to be completely managed by Eclipse then you should choose a different project type.

With a makefile-based project, then, you need to make appropriate changes to the Makefile yourself when you add sources to the project.  In this particular case, it looks like you should change

> ```
> OBJS = cpp_makefile.o
> ```

to

```
OBJS = cpp_makefile.o TestMe.o
```